# TimeOut in Thread with a query from io.vertx.ext.sql.SQLClient;

Tags: sql, postgresql, datasource, vert.x, sqlclient

Well, I a new developer with Vert.x... so, I have a problem with an implementation with a database connection.

In one or many querys, I have a lot of information like 160K records, those records will be in a JSON object throw GraphQL; so... when the query time is over 30000(ms)... the console says:

**Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1,5,main] has been blocked for 5026 ms, time limit is 2000 ms
io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked**

So I investigated about this, and I cannot find a way to resolve, maximize or set a bigger value to the query until these is finish or get all records.

Answer (score 2):

This question is actually covered in detail in the [official documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#blocking_code).

> you can’t call blocking operations directly from an event loop, as
>   that would prevent it from doing any other useful work

That's what you're doing at the moment - calling a blocking operation.

> An alternative way to run blocking code is to use a worker verticle A
>   worker verticle is always executed with a thread from the worker pool.

Run your "slow" code in a worker verticle. Communicate between EventLoop verticls and workers using [EventBus](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#event_bus). As long as you're inside same VM, passing even large collections over EventBus has no overhead.